# Переключение слайдов в swiper slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, swiper

На данный момент когда я в thumbs переключаю слайды, то активный слайд сразу передвигает контейнер, а не идет к нижнему слайду. Сейчас все наглядно покажу. Сейчас у меня вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а надо при нажатии на стрелки чтобы было вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```js
const sliderThumbs = new Swiper('.product-slider__thumbs .swiper-container', { // ищем слайдер превью по селектору
    // задаем параметры
    direction: 'vertical', // вертикальная прокрутка
    slidesPerView: 3, // показывать по 3 превью   
    spaceBetween: 10, // расстояние между слайдами
    navigation: { // задаем кнопки навигации
        nextEl: '.product-slider__next', // кнопка Next
        prevEl: '.product-slider__prev' // кнопка Prev
    },
    freeMode: true, // при перетаскивании превью ведет себя как при скролле
    breakpoints: { // условия для разных размеров окна браузера
        0: { // при 0px и выше
            direction: 'horizontal', // горизонтальная прокрутка
        },
        768: { // при 768px и выше
            direction: 'vertical', // вертикальная прокрутка
        }
    }
});
// Инициализация слайдера изображений
const sliderImages = new Swiper('.product-slider__images .swiper-container', { // ищем слайдер превью по селектору
    // задаем параметры
    direction: 'horizontal', // вертикальная прокрутка
    slidesPerView: 1, // показывать по 1 изображению
    spaceBetween: 16, // расстояние между слайдами
    mousewheel: true, // можно прокручивать изображения колёсиком мыши    
    navigation: { // задаем кнопки навигации
        nextEl: '.product-slider__next', // кнопка Next
        prevEl: '.product-slider__prev' // кнопка Prev
    },
    grabCursor: true, // менять иконку курсора
    thumbs: { // указываем на превью слайдер
        swiper: sliderThumbs // указываем имя превью слайдера
    },
    breakpoints: { // условия для разных размеров окна браузера
        0: { // при 0px и выше
            direction: 'horizontal', // горизонтальная прокрутка
        },
        768: { // при 768px и выше
            direction: 'horizontal', // вертикальная прокрутка
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.product-slider {
  color: #fff;
}
.product-slider .swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.product-slider__flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.product-slider__col {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 147px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.product-slider__prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 36%;
  z-index: 99;
}

.product-slider__next {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 36%;
  z-index: 99;
}

.slider__prev,
.slider__next {
  display: none;
}
.slider__prev:focus,
.slider__next:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.product-slider__thumbs {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 556px;
}

.product-slider__thumbs .swiper-slide-thumb-active .product-slider__image {
  opacity: 1;
  border: 2px solid #c40000;
  border-radius: 22px;
}

.product-slider__images {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 556px;
  width: 457px;
}

.product-slider__image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.product-slider__image img {
  border-radius: 22px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .product-slider__flex {
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
  .product-slider__col {
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top: 24px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .product-slider__images {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .product-slider__thumbs {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    width: calc(100% - 96px);
    margin: 0 16px;
  }
}

.product-slider__btn-thumb--next {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 36%;
  background-image: url(/images/product/arrow-next.svg);
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  z-index: 6;
}

.product-slider__btn-thumb--prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 36%;
  background-image: url(/images/product/arrow-next.svg);
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  z-index: 6;
}

.product-slider__btn-main--next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 47%;
  right: 0;
  background-image: url(/images/product/arrow-next.svg);
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  z-index: 6;
}

.product-slider__btn-main--prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 47%;
  left: 0;
  background-image: url(/images/product/arrow-next.svg);
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  z-index: 6;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
  <title>Lazer-teach</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Code+Pro:wght@400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<section class="product-slider">
          <div class="product-slider__flex">
            <div class="product-slider__col">
        
              <div class="product-slider__prev product-slider__btn-thumb--prev"></div> <!-- Кнопка для переключения на предыдущий слайд -->
        
              <div class="product-slider__thumbs">
                <div class="swiper-container"> <!-- Слайдер с превью -->
                  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                      <div class="product-slider__image"><img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080" alt=""/></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                      <div class="product-slider__image"><img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1081" alt=""/></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                      <div class="product-slider__image"><img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1082" alt=""/></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                      <div class="product-slider__image"><img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1083" alt=""/></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                      <div class="product-slider__image"><img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1084" alt=""/></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
        
              <div class="product-slider__next product-slider__btn-thumb--next"></div> <!-- Кнопка для переключения на следующий слайд -->
        
            </div>
        
            <div class="product-slider__images">
              <div class="swiper-container"> <!-- Слайдер с изображениями -->
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                 <div class="swiper-slide">
                  <div class="product-slider__image myImg">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080" alt="" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                  <div class="product-slider__image myImg">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1081" alt="" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                  <div class="product-slider__image myImg">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1082" alt="" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                  <div class="product-slider__image myImg">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1083" alt="" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">
                  <div class="product-slider__image myImg">
                    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1084" alt="" />
                  </div>
                </div>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="product-slider__prev product-slider__btn-main--prev"></div>
              <div class="product-slider__next product-slider__btn-main--next"></div>
            </div>
            
          </div>
        </section>

    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/8.0.0/swiper-bundle.min.js'></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
```